# zabbix connection to external database

Tags: database, mariadb, failover, zabbix

0

I am trying to setup zabbix with two database , one on localhost and another on diffrent machine.

zabbix server: 192.168.0.100
external database :192.168.0.154

I setup zabbix with localhostdatabaase and its working perfectly,Then I created sql dump file and put it in external database ie,192.168.0.154, but when I change the database ip in zabbix frontend PHP file it gives me permission denied,Ihave created all the required user in external database ie, zabbix@192.168.0.100 and assigned it all the permission still its giving permission denied error, also I have edited zabbix_server.conf file. please help struggling from past 3 days.

Comment: Please show the actual output when you check the permissions. You might just have missed a typo. Also show the actual content of the configuration files from Zabbix. Additionally, what distribution are you using?

Comment: Thank you gerald for the suggestion, actually everything was correct except 1 thing, so when setting up the zabbix before using "zcat /usr/share/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/server.sql.gz | mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -uzabbix -p zabbix" I am supposed to put the ipaddress of external database in zabbix-server.conf file "DBHost=192.168.0.154", but the issue was I was adding it after running it . I dont know the exact reason behind it but it worked.